# Is it possible to locally save/load OneNote 2016 notebooks in OneNote for Windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, cloud-storage, microsoft-onenote-2016, local-storage

I've been using Microsoft OneNote 2016 on a new Surface Book 3. I have several large notebooks through that app. I store each in different folders depending on what project they pertain to. However, as these notebooks have gotten larger in size (>50 pages) my OneNote 2016 has started lagging as well as causing other problems. I'm assuming it's because I'm on an old/not updated version of OneNote (i.e. OneNote 2016) so I am attempting to move to OneNote for Windows 10.

**Is it possible to load all of my old notebooks in OneNote for Windows 10 from their respective folders, and *leave them there*?** I do not want to move them exclusively to cloud storage, or even move them from the folders they're currently stored in.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to load all of my old notebooks in OneNote for Windows
> 10 from their respective folders, and leave them there?

No, you cannot use both versions of One Note with one set of local files.

To the best of my knowledge (Microsoft MVP Seminar a while back), conversion from One Note Desktop (which I am still using) to One Note for Windows 10 is a one-way street to the other version (Cloud Version).

That facilitates One Note files on any computer or any smart device and to do that, the files reside in the Microsoft cloud server (One Drive).

If you wish to maintain the files locally (I do), then use One Note 2016 Desktop.

Sometime down the road we will all have to change.